# Cant create account in firebase authentication

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-authentication

I'm experimenting firebase email authentication in my firebase chat application. But I cant signup. It shows error like account registration is unsuccessful.

```
protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode,
                                Intent data) {
    super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);

    if(requestCode == SIGN_IN_REQUEST_CODE) {
        if(resultCode == RESULT_OK) {
            Toast.makeText(this,
                    "Successfully signed in. Welcome!",
                    Toast.LENGTH_LONG)
                    .show();
            displayChatMessages();
        } else {
            Toast.makeText(this,
                    "We couldn't sign you in. Please try again later.",
                    Toast.LENGTH_LONG)
                    .show();

            // Close the app
            finish();
        }
    }

}
```

[Relevant code image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1DB1n.png)

Comment: Can you share Firebase Signin code? The above code is not showing any method calls via Firebase.

Comment: Am looking for **FirebaseAuth.signInWithCredential** something like this?

Comment: Please share all you relevant code.

Comment: @PratikKate : I have attached image. Actually I followed one tutorial for firebase chat app. In that tutorial there is no more extra code for signup.

Comment: You added an image of your code. That's a big no no here. Why not take time foemat your required signin code showing only the part you are facing doubt and put it in your question. And even in the image there is nothing related to firebase authentication

Comment: @Muhilan can you share the link of that tutorial? I will have a look into it and help you out.

Comment: https://code.tutsplus.com/tutorials/how-to-create-an-android-chat-app-using-firebase--cms-27397